# Can i use 2.5Amp on Raspberrypi 3B GPIO 5v pins?

Tags: power-supply

I'm thinking of using a 5V and 2.5Amp power supply to power up my Raspberrypi 3 model B over it's GPIO 5V PIN. Is it safe to use 5V 2A IN GPIO PIN?

Comment: why are you asking if it safe to connect 5V to a GPIO pin? .... you do not power  the RPI through a GPIO pin ... always use a power pin  ..... just because it is in a GPIO connector, it does not make it an actual GPIO pin

Comment: I hv a 5v 2.5amp adapter which is not micro usb friendly so i thought of using it with Rpi 5v and gnd.

Comment: We are trying to point out that the power and ground pins are not GPIO.  It is misleading to call them GPIO (some people then connect 5V to an actual GPIO and kill their Pi).

Answer (score 1):

You can power the Pi using the 5V and ground pins on the expansion header.

Please note that the power and ground pins are NOT GPIO and it is wrong to refer to them as such.

See https://pinout.xyz/ for details of the pins on the expansion header.

The amperage of your 5V power supply doesn't matter as long as it is enough to power the Pi and connected peripherals.  For safety it might be sensible to add a 2.5 amp fuse to your circuit (not to protect the Pi, to protect things connected to the Pi).